# Azure DevOps Analytics OData Feed Timeline Expansion

Tags: powerbi, azure-pipelines, odata, metrics

I am attempting to pull Azure DevOps Pipeline metrics via PowerBI and using an OData feed. However, when I get the information back from the analytics tool, I am only receiving data from the last 180 days.

Is there a way to expand this time period  to the last 1 year or 365 days?

I am looking for the capability to pull the last 1 year's worth of data in order to show proper pipeline metrics to the higher ups within the company.